# How to make cMake use Debug compilation mode for only a subset of directories in a project?

Tags: cmake

Rephrased the question.

I have the following problem:

My project has several binaries and libraries that reside in distinct sub-directories under the main project folder.
It is useful to be able to debug only a subset of them, without recompiling the whole project in Debug mode.

I want to be able to only change the compilation mode for this subset in a semi-automatic fashion.

How can I accomplish this using CMake?

Comment: what about passing build type during CMake invokation? Like `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

Comment: Only if I want to compile the whole project in Debug mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change the build type, the whole project will be recompiled from scratch. Usually you keep 2 separated build tree, one configured debug and one configured release.

Note that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` can be set from command line or from cmake-gui, you shouldn't set it in the CMakeLists.txt file.

---

To compile only some part of your project in debug mode, you can proceed as follow. In your main CMakeLists.txt, before including any subdirectory, define the following macro:

```
macro (CHECK_IF_DEBUG)
  if (NOT (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug))
    get_filename_component(THIS_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE " " "_" THIS_DIR ${THIS_DIR}) #Replace spaces with underscores
    if (DEFINED DEBUG_${THIS_DIR})
      message(STATUS "Note: Targets in directory ${THIS_DIR} will be built Debug") #A reminder
      set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
    endif()
  endif()
endmacro()
```

Then, in each subdirectory add (at the beginning of the CMakelists.txt) the macro call

```
 CHECK_IF_DEBUG()
```

When you need to temporarily debug a part (subdirectory) of your project, open your project in cmake-gui, and define a variable ("Add Entry") with name `DEBUG_<DirectoryName>`. You can define multiple ones. **If your directory name contains spaces, in the variable name replace them with underscores**. Don't forget to click `Configure` and `Generate` from cmake-gui to make the change effective. The value assigned to the variable is not important, it can be left empty.

When you are finished debugging, go back to cmake-gui and remove the corresponding entries. *Don't forget to `Configure` and `Generate`*.

I have tested it in a small project and it seems to work properly.

Note: If you create more than one target (`add_library` or `add_executable`) in the same CMakeLists.txt (=in the same subdirectory), I haven't found a way to have one target built in one way and one target in another: the only thing that seems to count is the value of the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` directory when CMake is finished parsing the file.

---

In answer to your comment, you can have a reminder printed at build time by adding in the block the following line:

```
add_custom_target(info_${THIS_DIR} ALL COMMAND echo Targets in directory ${THIS_DIR} are built Debug)
```

See [add_custom_target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).

Comment: If you read my question, you will see that I want to compile part of it in debug mode. Sometimes this is necessary, otherwise I might have too many debug messages unrelated with the issue at hand.

Comment: @MarcoCosta As you see from the 2 reactions you got, the question is not clear at all. It would probably become an interesting one, so it would be worth to rephrase it.

Comment: I edited the question and title. I would appreciate your input on how to make the question better.

Comment: @MarcoCosta Yeah, *now* it's a nice question! :) I'll see what I can do about it...

Comment: I like your solution. I also couldn't figure out how to compile just one source file in debug. If you could add a macro to add a fake target to tell at compile time if the directory is being built in any mode other than Release, I will accept it. The way I did, the fake target will be called even if not building anything.

Answer (score -2):

The solution I came with is as follows:

I created a macro that will read a config file in the binary directory and set the compilation type based on its content.

When this file changes, cMake will rerun on that directory only and it will recompile it also, because its dependencies changed. This is exactly what I needed.

The macro follows:

```
macro(set_buildmode _local_app_name)
  if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BUILDMODE)
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BUILDMODE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
    message(" *** Creating file 'BUILDMODE' with type '${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}' for '${_local_app_name}'")
  endif()
  configure_file( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BUILDMODE 
                  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BUILDMODE.junk)
  file(READ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BUILDMODE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  string(STRIP ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
endmacro()
```

To make sure I always know if I have compiled in any other mode other than release, I also have this macro:

```
macro(add_buildmode_message _local_app_name_full)
  get_filename_component(_local_app_name ${_local_app_name_full} NAME)
  add_custom_target(Checking_BUILDMODE_for_${_local_app_name} ALL
                    COMMAND bash -c "if [ \"${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}\" != \"Release\" ] ; then echo -e \"       ${BoldRed}${_local_app_name} was built with type '${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}'${ColourReset}\" ; fi"
                 VERBATIM)
endmacro()
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
set(appname example)
###### Call set_buildmode here
set_buildmode(${appname})
set(${appname}_SRCS
example.cpp
main.cpp)

set(${appname}_HDRS
example.h)

set(${appname}_LIBS)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

execute_process(COMMAND ln -frs ${${appname}_HDRS} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set(MYLIB_VERSION_MINOR 1)
set(MYLIB_VERSION_PATCH 0)
set(MYLIB_VERSION_STRING
    ${MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR}.${MYLIB_VERSION_MINOR}.${MYLIB_VERSION_PATCH})
add_library(${appname} ${${appname}_SRCS})
target_link_libraries (${appname} ${${appname}_LIBS} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})

##### Add the fake target for checking the build mode
add_buildmode_message(${appname})
set_target_properties(${appname} PROPERTIES VERSION ${MYLIB_VERSION_STRING}
                       SOVERSION ${MYLIB_VERSION_MAJOR})
install(TARGETS ${appname} DESTINATION lib)
```